# join / union in presto to keep email in one column

Tags: join, outer-join, presto

I'm trying to join two tables together in presto,

```
select o.email
, o.user_id
, c.email
, c.sessions
from datasource o
full join datasource2 c
on o.email = c.email
```

this yields:

```
email                user_id     email            sessions
jeff@sessions.com    123         NULL             NULL
mike@berkley.com     987         NULL             NULL
jared@swiss.com      384         jared@swiss.com  14
steph@berk.com       333         NULL             NULL
NULL                 NULL        lisa@hart.com    12
```

the problem with this is that I want to do multiple joins on multiple data sources using `email`, the only workaround I can think of is to use this as a subquery, and create a new column that takes one, and if null, takes the other, then perform the full join on datasource3, rinse repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use COALESCE which will chose the not null of the two values. 
COALESCE is very useful for a lot of things. It can take more than two values and will return the first non NULL value it gets. If all of them are NULL it will simply return NULL.

```
SELECT 
  COALLESCE(o.email, c.email) AS email
  , o.user_id
  , c.sessions
FROM datasource o
FULL JOIN datasource2 c
ON o.email = c.email
```

For the official documentation on COALESCE see here:
https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html